# value для select при загрузке

Tags: javascript, html

есть селект со значениями от 1 до 10. как мне сделать, что при загрузке страницы у меня в селекте сразу было выбрано значение семь?

Comment: атрибут selected )) что-то я не подумал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно поставить атрибут selected в нужный тебе option.Пример:

```
<select name="test">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7" selected>7</option>
<option value="8">9</option>
<option value="9">10</option>
</select>
```